# MS-SQL: UPDATE fails with reference in a JOIN

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

I have a question on an UPDATE statement; it runs through but isn't updating the values as it should.

I've double checked that the criteria are valid and it preforms as expected without the lookup reference. It is just when I reference the other table that it fails.

```
UPDATE dbo.IFSPs_PovertyLevel
SET PovertyLevel = 
    (
    CASE
        WHEN    (
                PovertyLevel IS NULL
                AND ifspsign IS NOT NULL
                AND ifspsign BETWEEN L.BegDate AND L.EndDate
                AND CONVERT(MONEY,income) <= L.TwoPL
                ) THEN 2
        ELSE PovertyLevel
        END
    )
FROM dbo.IFSPs_PovertyLevel PL
INNER JOIN EI_Archive.dbo.Lookup_PovertyLevel L
    ON PL.family_size = L.Family_Size
```

Comment: Is this the working query or the one that is failing ? We need the one that fails.

Comment: You need something here to know which row to get the values from. The way you have this coded it will pull the same row from Lookup_PovertyLevel. I would assume you need a certain row based on some join criteria?

Comment: Write it as a `SELECT`, then it's much easier to convert to an `UPDATE`. It appears you are missing a `JOIN` here.

Comment: @M.Page - This is the query that is failing

Comment: I added the join and the query does work as a SELECT but it is still not making the updates.

Comment: Obviously there must be some typo here. It's confusing, which one of the tables is aliased as PL and why is not PL used anywhere else? Is this copied exactly as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you'll want a join between your two tables, unless there is only one row in Lookup_PovertyLevel. Here's how to add a join in an UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE PL
SET PovertyLevel = 
    (
    CASE
        WHEN    (
                PovertyLevel IS NULL
                AND ifspsign IS NOT NULL
                AND ifspsign BETWEEN L.BegDate AND L.EndDate
                AND CONVERT(MONEY,income) <= L.TwoPL
                ) THEN 2
        ELSE PovertyLevel
        END
    )
FROM dbo.IFSPs_PovertyLevel PL
    INNER JOIN EI_Archive.dbo.Lookup_PovertyLevel L ON <join_condition>
```

Without this, the query will try to use all rows from the lookup table, and will probably end up using the last row as the final value for all rows updated in the target table.

Edit to demonstrate the same query redone with a WHERE instead of a CASE:

```
UPDATE PL
SET PovertyLevel = 2
--select pl.povertylevel, ifspsign,L.BegDate,L.EndDate, * 
FROM dbo.IFSPs_PovertyLevel PL
    INNER JOIN EI_Archive.dbo.Lookup_PovertyLevel L ON <join_condition>
WHERE PovertyLevel IS NULL
                AND ifspsign IS NOT NULL
                AND ifspsign BETWEEN L.BegDate AND L.EndDate
                AND CONVERT(MONEY,income) <= L.TwoPL
```

Note from HLGEM - I edited to add a commented out select sstatement inteh second update, so that the OP can see exactly what would be returned in the query for the appropriate values. This si helpful indetermining what will change as a result of teh update and makes it easier to see if there is a problem. I do think the second query is the one to use instead of the convoluted CASE sttaement. It will update fewer records and be faster than the orginal as well.

Comment: I've added the JOIN and condition and the query is still not making the expected updates.

Comment: This particular query can be rewritten with a WHERE clause instead of the CASE statement (since you're setting PovertyLevel = PovertyLevel if the CASE condition is not met).

Running the re-written query as a select might give you a better idea why it isn't updating rows you think it should. I'll edit my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: Nice update HLGEM. The only reason I'm not recommending the revised query as an update statement is because I assume there will be other cases added to update the value under other conditions. If that isn't right, the second UPDATE query should be used instead of the CASE statement.

Comment: I will admit to some extra confusion here. I'm not sure who made what edit where. Yes, there are traditional cases added, lots, but I wanted to keep the original question as concise as possible.

Comment: Fine to keep the query concise for the purposes of the question, and your query is fine. The second UPDATE statement in my original answer is an alternative way to run the same update, based on a single CASE condition. If you run that as a SELECT (HLGEM's edit to add the commented-out SELECT query) it should give you the data rows that will be updated and the field values used in the update. If it returns zero rows, then it gives you something to debug :)

Comment: The second UPDATE statement did give me what is expected. I'm actually rewriting a very long, very old query that had many update statements into a new stored procedure. (I thought I chose an "easy" one to demonstrate for my team too!)

Comment: I still had to keep some of the case/when/then but moving the majority of the criteria to the where clause was the solution. thank you for all your help.